# Track closing of the created window in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am making a OAuth login for my site. When user clicks the OAuth link, I want to open a new window and when that window closes, I want to update the parent page.

This is what I thought of:

```
$('.social').click(function()
{

    var url = $(this).attr('href'), newWindow;

    newWindow = window.open('', 'closeWhenDone', 'width=500, height=800');
    newWindow.onbeforeunload = getOAuth;
    newWindow.location.href = url;

    return false;

});
```

However, once the page redirects to the social network for authorization, the event listener is gone, hence the parent page does not reload.

What is the way to trigger an event when the created window is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned it's for a social network OAuth, this would mean the popup is a different domain. So no, you can't fire events because of the Same-Origin Policy. If you could fire events on that window, you'd be able to fire events to steal the user's password too. For example, you could setup an onchange for the username/password textbox and try to steal it. Hence, if it's a different domain, you can't script it. You could even edit the DOM to make it post their password to your domain instead by changing the form `action`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that info, but my question is specifically just track when the window is closed, it's impossible as well?

Comment: I don't believe any communication is allowed. Even "close" gives " information leak" such as how long the user is on the site